# Where I put zbar.jar when I have 2 modules depends on it?

Tags: android, android-studio, zbar-sdk, zbar

I inherited an project that I imported to Android Studio.

There's 3 modules (the app and 2 libraries). In the end of the conversion from Eclipse, both the app and one the libraries uses zbar.jar.

After removing all other duplicates found, the last is zbar.jar. But I don't know which is least effort way to remove that redundance.

Below the build.gradle's from app and the library:
App:
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.google.zxing.client.android.customer"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21

        testApplicationId "com.google.zxing.client.android.customer.test"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
        debug {
            renderscriptDebuggable true
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
    sourceSets { main { res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res', 'src/main/res/values-21'] } }

    dexOptions {
        incremental true
        javaMaxHeapSize "3g"

    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':tecladoLib')
    compile project(':zBarScannerActivity')
    compile files('libs/android-logging-log4j-1.0.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/core.jar')
    compile files('libs/HockeySDK.jar')
    compile files('libs/ksoap2-android-assembly-3.0.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar')
    compile files('libs/log4j-1.2.17.jar')
    compile files('libs/zbar.jar')
    androidTestCompile 'com.jayway.android.robotium:robotium-solo:5.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
}
```

Library:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/zbar.jar')
}
```